# Haskell check if a list of lists has an empty list

Tags: list, haskell

I have tried to create a function that determines if a list of lists has an empty list. However so far I don't seem to find any luck. So far I have tried using:
`hasEmpty (x:xs) = if null x then True else False`
However this only return true if the first list is empty.
I also tried:
`hasEmpty (x:xs) = if null x || null xs then True else False`
But it produces the same result.
I have also tried using **any** and **elem** but I couldn't get it working.
I am truly stumped on this. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: You're looking for [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science))

Comment: What did you try with `any`? The solution with `any` and `null` is almost trivial.

Comment: I tried using ```hasEmpty [[a]] = if any (==null) [[a]] then True else False``` but  it kept throwing an error.  I now have realized it was an error on my part because I used any wrongly.  My problem has been solved now thanks to Francis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of `any` is `any :: Foldable t => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> Bool` (use `:t any`) to get this.

There are two arguments:

1. The first argument is a function which takes a value and returns a boolean, such as `null`
2. The second argument is a foldable, such as a list

Hence we can simply use `any null` on a list.

```
lst = [[1],[],[3]]
lst2 = [[1],[3],[2]]

any null lst -- returns True
any null lst2 -- returns False
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursion always has a base case. When you're dealing with lists, it's an empty list. If we try running an `anyNull` function on an empty list, it should return false.

```
anyNull :: [a] -> Bool
anyNull [] = False
```

But we also need to match the non-empty list and converge toward the base case. This is done by recursively calling the function on the list's tail. Fortunately pattern matching makes it easy to tell if the first element is an empty list, and then to handle the case where it is *not* empty.

```
anyNull :: [a] -> Bool
anyNull [] = False
anyNull ([]:_) = True 
anyNull (_:xs) = anyNull xs
```